# Icon to request device rotation

Tags: icons, responsive-design, screen-orientation

Is there an existing icon that is recognized as a request / suggestion that a user rotate their mobile device?

I am converting an OLD website to be more mobile friendly. (responsive) I have existing forms that already fit decently if viewed in landscape mode, (My test device is relatively small, the Samsung Galaxy Avant) so one option might be to give them alternate content asking them to rotate their device for a better view.

I'm not sure if a tilting rectangle or rotational arrows (or combination of the two) is better. (Along with, not instead of, English text)

Comment: In typing the question, I thought of another way to search and came up with this: https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+tilt+icon&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=cKOfVdSpGIO1eayvg8AF&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=968&bih=596 I'll look through those and see if anything works well. I'm still open to any suggestions.

Comment: Displaying the form in landscape mode will naturally prompt the user to rotate the device.

Answer (score 1):

This search seems to yield quite a few results: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rotate+screen+icon&espv=2&biw=1342&bih=648&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=IaSfVcmCB8at7AbSwIHYBQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ

Most of them seem to be based on a stylised phone icon either show at an angle with one or two arrows to denote rotation direction or the device overlayed in both portrait and landscape orientations with a double headed arrow denoting some amount of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would go both **tilting rectangle and arrow**.

The **arrows** a standarized icon **for refreshing/synchronizing** so I won't use them alone.
The rectangle alone doesn't say too much by itself, the motion part .

Android uses something like this (although I don't really like that arrows) and the labeling also helps a lot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself first why you need an icon? Rotating one's mobile device is a fairly common and one could argue, intuitive interaction. If people need more room, they often naturally tilt it into landscape by default.

I'd argue the icon is completely superfluous. The number of people that would a) be frustrated that things don't fit well in portrait and b) not know that they can rotate the screen and c) understand what that icon means is probably really small.